# SQL Server has lost tcp/ip connectivity, works locally

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

An SQL Server install on a VM was stopped incorrectly this morning.  When brought back up, it communicates normally on the local machine.  It no longer works on TCP/IP.  Attempts to communicate with the server from SSMS on a differnt machine result in

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server.  The server was not found or is not accessible.  
Very that the instance name is correct and that the SQL Server is 
configured to allow remote connections. (provider:Named Pipes Provider,
error:40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)(Microsoft SQL Server, 
Error 1326)

    The user name or password is incorrect
```

The username and password work fine when they are used locally.  Have tested Windows Auth locally, sql user remotely (we don't have a domain)

In SQL Server Configuration Manager > Sql Server Network Configuration > Protocols for MSSQLServer > TCP/IP > IP Addresses  everything appears correctly configured.  The IPv6 IPv4 addresses are correct, and IPAll has the correct port (default 1433)

The server can ping multiple hosts on the network.  They can ping it back.  It's only a single non-routeable subnet.  192.168.0.*

The name of the pc matches the name of the sql server from `SELECT @@SERVERNAME`

The server version is 10.50.6000 which maps to SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

First of all 1433 Port allow in Firewall (Inbound/Outbound rule)
After then try login with 
ServerName: IPAddress\InstanceName,1433
Authentication : SQL Server Authentication